# Laravel Increment Column Value

Tags: laravel

This has to be a simple fix, but it's not clicking with me. I am simply trying to find a record in my table and increment one column.

```
    $visits = DB::table('recently_visited')
        ->where('profile_id',$user->id)
        ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->first();
```

This accurately returns the database record as when I dd $visits, here's an example of the output.

```
{#197 ▼
  +"id": 6
  +"visitor_id": 2
  +"profile_id": 2
  +"times_visited": 6
  +"last_visit": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
```

But then when I attach the "increments onto it...

```
    $visits->increment('times_visited');
```

I get the error...Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::increment()

I have also tried doing the following...

```
$visits = DB::table('recently_visited')
            ->increment('times_visited')
            ->where('profile_id',$user->id)
            ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();
```

But I get...Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on integer

Thanks!

Comment: OMG, yes it does work when omitting "first()". I figured it was something simple. Much appreciated!

Comment: Haha, you're welcome! Glad you saw my suggestion before I deleted it. It was a hunch, but I wasn't certain. :) In the documentation, ->increment() was always called on the full resultset -- and in the Laravel method definition for increment I saw that increment() returns an int, so it does not support method chaining after it.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Omitting "first()" and chaining "increment()" to the query works.

-- Submitted by mmccaff